# How to find number of subcategories per category in excel?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

I have data of sales of products across teams. Each row corresponds to a single sales transaction. I need to get a count of number of kinds of products sold per team.

I tried Pivot table and gives count of transactions as they're the individual rows.

Expected result should be like : 
Team 1: 3 products
Team 2: 5 products
Team 3: 3 products etc.
Existing output is :

Team 1: Product 1: 100; Product 2: 200; Product 3: 100 (counting rows available)

Comment: you want to search `Count Unique with Condition in Excel`.  There are many examples on how to do this.

Comment: @ScottCraner, there is no condition. There are over 100 categories and I need number of subcategories per category.

Comment: Your category is the condition.  You would copy paste the list of categories, use remove duplicates to get a unique list then use that as the condition referencing the data.

Comment: I have over 100 categories. And if anything, the list will get bigger. How do I add the list of 100 categories into the condition?

Comment: Then you may want vba to do this.  A pivot table will do it.

Comment: You do not add 100 categories you create the list of the 100 categories then in the next column you put the formula that references the one cell for the condition back to the dataset.

Comment: Pivot table is only showing the row count at transaction level and not at subcategory level. As I mentioned in the sample output above, it gives like this:
Team 1: Product 1: 100; Product 2: 200; Product 3: 100 (counting rows available)

Comment: "You do not add 100 categories you create the list of the 100 categories then in the next column you put the formula that references the one cell for the condition back to the dataset"

Didn't get you. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: The first question linked shows you what I mean, you would get a unique list of the categories in column D, then in E you would put the formula.

Comment: Not really. It's for a specific usecase. "Last name" and a particular subcategory, which is mentioned "Fraud"
I'm looking at a general one. I can't provide every single one here.

Comment: Do you mind providing a sample formula, imagining I have transaction in B, subcategory in C, Category in D? And not equating to any particular value?

Comment: Did you google the statement I provided?  There are many examples from other websites how to do this.

Comment: Will do. But the thing is I don't have a condition here. It's more of Group by in SQL.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Just did. No result. It's all about one level count using pivot tables. Pivot tables don't help here as they're giving count of transactions and not type of products per team.

Comment: The second part of this one: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3403-excel-count-unique-based-on-another-column.html

Comment: This one explains the formula in detail: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria

Comment: So does this one: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-numeric-values-with-criteria

Comment: And another: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2017/08/28/count-unique-distinct-values-based-on-a-condition/

Comment: Not one of those talks about pivot tables.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for the links. I had a problem with finding the right key words to lookup on google. :)
I'm sure I'd be able to do it. (Y)